# How to make website appear as a fullsite on mobile device?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

How can i make my website appear as a fullsite on mobile device. I am using jquery-mobile on the desktop site, and want to display web page as a normal desktop website page on the mobile device. Where user can zoom in and out.

So far i am able to make site appear on the mobile but the user have to slide the page up and down to see all the content on the page.

And to zoom i use  (however, this only allows to zoom.)

Comment: Isn't that how all mobile sites work? You only have x amount of screen space and showing the full site makes it impossible to read so when you zoom to actually interact with the site scrolling is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, commonly, a jQuery Mobile page should contain this line in HTML head section,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It will ask mobile browser display jQuery Mobile page as normal zoom scale, such as,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    ......
</head>
```

Are you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to make a desktop site display properly on a mobile device is to use media queries.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

However, if your site was not designed to be responsive from the get go, this can be tricky.